# deploy c# application to linux instance amazon ec2

Tags: linux, winforms, amazon-ec2

I have written a winform c# application, how can i deploy it in a linux instance on amazon ec2?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) on your linux ec2 instance in order to run a winforms app.

You can find information about deploying on a mono machine here: http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment

Is this what you would like to do?